# PIL ImageTk equivalent in Python 3.x

Tags: python, png, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm developing an application with Tkinter that uses a database of `png` image files for icons. In order to use said images in the application, I open them using PIL's `Image.open`, run it through the `ImageTk.PhotoImage` function, then pass it to the widget constructor.

The problem is, I'm trying to port my entire project over to Python 3.x, and because of PIL's lack of support for Python 3, I have no idea how to load the icons into the application.

If anyone knew of a solution that would allow me to use the icons without having to convert all of them to `.gif` bitmaps, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 10):

PNG files, even with transparency, are correctly displayed in tkinter and ttk in python 3.4.1 on Linux, even though only GIF and PPM/PGM support is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html).

> [image: Example PNG File With Transparency And Alpha]

Above PNG image contains transparency.

```python
from tkinter import *          

root = Tk()                    

photo = PhotoImage(file="example.png")
photo_label = Label(image=photo)
photo_label.grid()             
photo_label.image = photo      

text = Label(text="Text") # included to show background color
text.grid()    

root.mainloop()
```

Above code renders the image correctly with transparency as seen below:

> [image: PNG Test Image In Python 3.4.1 tkinter with text]

Please note that the screenshot was made on a setup without window decoration and with dark GUI color scheme.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pillow](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) to work with `png` images, in Python 3.3 or older versions.

Taken from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.0.0):

> Pillow >= 2.0.0 supports Python versions: 2.6, 2.7, 3.2, 3.3. Pillow <
>   2.0.0 supports Python versions: 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

**The example displays an image on the canvas.**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
# From the PIL (Python Imaging Library) module, we import the Image and ImageTk modules.


self.img = Image.open("tatras.jpg")
self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)


# Tkinter does not support JPG images internally. As a workaround, we
# use the Image and ImageTk modules.

canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.img.size[0]+20,  height=self.img.size[1]+20)

# We create the Canvas widget. It takes the size of the image into account. It is 20px wider and 20px higher than the actual image size.

canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras)
```