# How to draw images in tkinter window

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, draw

How do I draw an image in a tkinter window (I'm using python 3.3)? I'm looking for a statement which would draw an image at a given position on a tkinter window.

yeah...

Any answers would be appreciated. And here's the source code of the program (if it can be called that) that I want to use the code in, in case you need it.

```
from tkinter import *

class craftClass():
    def __init__(self, x = 80, y = 80, xmotion = 0, ymotion = 0, health = 20):
        self.xPos, self.yPos = x, y
        self.dx, self.dy = xmotion, ymotion
    def moveCraft(self):
        self.xPos += self.dx
        self.yPos += self.dy

class missileClass():
    def __init__(self, x = 0 , y = 0):
        self.xPos, self.yPos = x, y

class alienClass():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.xPos, self.yPos = x, y

    def moveForCraft(self, craftX, craftY):
        if self.xPos < craftX:
            self.xPos += 2
        elif self.xPos > craftX:
            self.xPos -= 2
        else:
            pass

    if self.yPos < craftY:
        self.yPos += 2
    elif self.yPos > craftY:
        self.yPos -= 2
    else:
        pass

craft = craftClass()
missileArray = []
alienArray = []

def keypress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
x = event.char
if x == "w":
    craft.dy = 1
elif x == "s":
    craft.dy = -1
elif x == "a":
    craft.dx = -1
elif x == "d":
    craft.dx = 1
else:
    print(x)

root = Tk()
print(craft.dx)
while True:
try:
    root.bind_all('<Key>', keypress)
    craft.moveCraft()
    root.update()
except TclError:
    print("exited. tcl error thrown. llop broken")
    break
```

I'm well aware that the spacing is sorta messed up, but that's something that happened while copying

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to use a `Canvas` widget to put your images in specified (x,y) positions.

In Python 3, you can do like this:

```
import tkinter

tk = tkinter.Tk()
can = tkinter.Canvas(tk)
can.pack()
img = tkinter.PhotoImg("<path/to/image_file>.gif")
can.create_image((x_coordinate, y_coordinate), img)
```

Please note that due to Python 3 not having an official `PIL`***** release, you are limited to read images of type `GIF`, `PGM` or `PPM` - if you need other file types, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068872/pil-imagetk-equivalent-in-python-3-x).

The Canvas widget is quite powerfull, and allows you to position your images, shows what is on it through an `"canvas.update"` call, and remove an item displayer with a `"canvas.delete(item_id)"` call. Check its [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm).

While Tkinter should be enough for your simple game, consider taking a look at [`Pygame`](http://pygame.org), for a better multimedia support, or maybe [Pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/), or even higher level multimedia framework called [Kivy](http://kivy.org/).

*****(update): As of 2015, there is Pillow - a fork that is a drop in replacement of the old PIL project, and which resumed proper development of the project, including support for Python 3.x

Answer (score 4):

### **The example displays an image on the canvas.**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

> From the PIL (Python Imaging Library) module, we import the Image and
>   ImageTk modules.

```
self.img = Image.open("tatras.jpg") //your image name :)
self.tatras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
```

> Tkinter does not support JPG images internally. As a workaround, we
>   use the Image and ImageTk modules.

```
canvas = Canvas(self, width=self.img.size[0]+20,
    height=self.img.size[1]+20)
```

We create the Canvas widget. It takes the size of the image into account. It is 20px wider and 20px higher than the actual image size.

```
canvas.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=self.tatras)
```

---

Reference see: https://tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_canvas.htm

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on the file format.  Tkinter has a [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) class which can be used in `Labels` quite easily if your image is a `.gif`.  You can also add them to canvas widgets reasonably easily.  Otherwise, you might want to use PIL to convert an image to a `PhotoImage`.