# What Is The Most Basic Way To Render Pixels In Python?

Tags: python, rendering

How can I directly access the color of pixels and create windows in Python? I have found ways like Pillow and Turtle, but what are they built on? And what are the ones supporting them built on? I am looking for the most native and basic way to render pixels.

If this is not specific enough, then how can I directly make a window of size 100x100 and coordinates (0,0) on the screen and make a red box of size 10x10 in the middle of the screen and then clear the window and redraw the box 5 pixels to the right? I want to all of this without using a library to make it easier. Hopefully it is in a way where I could write my own library.

In turtle, the first render might look like this:

```python
import turtle
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.setpos(-5,-5)
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.pencolor("red")
turtle.pensize(1)
turtle.pendown()
for _ in range(5):
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(10)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(1)
    turtle.left(90)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284311/python-tkinter-how-to-work-with-pixels Are you talking browser windows or OS windows or what?

Comment: tkinter, pyqt, pywidgets,..... or OpenGL Python. GL writing the library yourself

Comment: Python itself doesn't have any concept of pixels, you need a library on top of it to deal with that.

Comment: @Jonas OS windows, I think. The same window that pops up with Turtle. I have looked at TKinter too, but is that as basic as it gets?

Comment: @rioV8 
Yes, writing the library myself is exactly what I want to do. I edited the question to say that. I do that with OpenGL?

Comment: @Mark Ransom So what is the most basic library and what language will deal with pixels?

Comment: There are many such libraries, all completely different.  Recommending a library is specifically discouraged by SO.

Comment: @Mark But they can’t all be the most basic. So what are those libraries built on?

Comment: C, probably....

Comment: @Mark Then what C function can set the color of a pixel?

Comment: C, like Python, doesn't have a concept of a pixel inherent to the language.  You need to use a library or OS API.

Comment: If you want to write the library yourself than you are not allowed to use OpenGL because it is a library, you need to write the interface to the OpenGL API and Window interface yourself

Comment: @Mark What does have a concept of pixels?

Comment: There are only so many times I can tell you.  You don't seem to be capable of understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking (though I would have been fine with something more basic) was that

> [TKinter] is the standard Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit, and is Python's de facto standard GUI.

From TKinter’s Wikipedia page.
TKinter is Python’s most basic library for drawing and it is the only one built in to the standard library of Python.